# Работа с видео

Tags: c#, xna, разработка-игр

Приветствую всех, кто зашел сюда :)
Пишу небольшую игру, в которой, мне необходимо вставить видео и проиграть его, что-то типа интро.С этим проблем нет, все воспроизводит, но, как например мне воспроизвести его один раз и остановить после его окончания?
**IsLooped = false** не помогает. Все равно идет в цикл.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, стоит завести перечисление с флагами-состояниями.Так для видео будет свое состояние и, пока игровой процесс будет в этом самом состоянии, проверяй сколько времени прошло от начала показа видео и сравнивай с продолжительностью интро. Т.е. две переменных - продолжительность видео, и время от начала показа видео (естественно, в каждом кадре его необходимо увеличивать).
В принципе, можно сразу рассчитать время, в которое должно закончиться видео и с ним уже и сравнить прошедшее время.

Comment: Спасибо, об этом я как-то и не подумал. Думал может какой-нибудь более простой способ есть :)

Comment: Может и есть. Со стандартными средствами xna я много не работал. Но мне кажется, что такой нет, т. к. xna вряд ли умеет сама отслеживать, что надо запускать после просмотра ролика.

Comment: Вроде что-то получилось

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось)